# Using ANT to precompile handlebars.js templates

Tags: ant, handlebars.js

I'd like to use ant to compile several of my handlebars templates.

The command I'd like to run is:

```
handlebars templates -f templates/hbs.js
```

My ant file has the following:

```
<exec executable="handlebars">
    <arg value="${src.templates.dir}"/>
    <arg value="-f"/>
    <arg value="${src.templates.dir}/hbs2.js"/>
</exec>
```

I get a BUILD FAILED error where it reads

> Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannont run program "handlebars": CreateProcess error-2, the system cannot find the file specified.

I've also tried

```
<exec executable="handlebars.exe">
```

with the same result. Handlebars works because I can run the command from a terminal window from the same location as my ant build files.

I've got handlebars installed through node.js. I know I can probably get it to work by using node to build my project, but I'm hoping I don't have to convert my other ant tasks.

Comment: Could it just be a path problem? I don't know my way around ant but many build tools use a specific set of paths rather than relying on the `PATH` in the environment.

Comment: Hmmm... That's interesting. But then, how would I call it when it's installed in node.js?

Comment: You have a `handlebars` command for compiling your templates somewhere, right? Have you tried specifying the full path to that command in your ant file? That will at least let you know if you have a PATH problem or not.

Comment: Thanks @MarkO'Connor ! I'll just call a RTFM on myself. That totally worked. I wish there was a way for me to upvote ya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the windows section of the "exec" task:

- http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html

Comment: Yeah, it's this: '<exec executable="cmd.exe">
 <arg line="/c handlebars templates -f templates/hbs.js" />
</exec>'